# Authentication and authorization with Flatiron's Resourceful & Restful

Tags: javascript, node.js, flatiron.js

I want to implement authentication and authorization in the [Flatiron](http://flatironjs.org/) stack (using Flatiron, Resourceful and Restful). I want to require that a user has the necessary permissions, when trying to change a resource. In the Restful Readme file, there's a [note about authorization](https://github.com/flatiron/restful#resource-security):

> There are several ways to provide security and authorization for
>   accessing resource methods exposed with restful. The recommended
>   pattern for authorization is to use resourceful's ability for `before`
>   and `after` hooks. In these hooks, you can add additional business logic
>   to restrict access to the resource's methods.
>
> It is **not** recommended to place authorization logic in the routing
>   layer, as in an ideal world the router will be a reflected interface
>   of the resource. In theory, the security of the router itself should
>   be somewhat irrelevant since the resource could have multiple
>   reflected interfaces that all required the same business logic.
>
> **TL;DR; For security and authorization, you should use resourceful's
>   `before` and `after` hooks.**

So authorization can be handled by Resourceful's hooking system.

My actual problem is the authentication process at the beginning of every HTTP request.

Let's say I have a resource `Post`, a `User` and a resource `Session`. The REST API is being defined by using Restful. My main concern for this question is to ensure that a user has a session when creating a post. Other methods like `save`, `update` or for other resources like creating a user should work analogous.

File `app.js`:

```
var flatiron = require('flatiron');
var app = flatiron.app;

app.resources = require('./resources.js');

app.use(flatiron.plugins.http);
app.use(restful);
app.start(8080, function(){
  console.log('http server started on port 8080');
});
```

File `resources.js`:

```
var resourceful = require('resourceful');

var resources = exports;

resources.User = resourceful.define('user', function() {
  this.restful = true;
  this.string('name');
  this.string('password');
});

resources.Session = resourceful.define('session', function() {
  // note: this is not restful
  this.use('memory');
  this.string('session_id');
});

resources.Post = resourceful.define('post', function() {
  this.restful = true;
  this.use('memory');
  this.string('title');
  this.string('content');
});

resources.Post.before('create', function authorization(post, callback) {
  // What should happen here?
  // How do I ensure, a user has a session id?

  callback();
});
```

There's also a [runnable version of the code](http://runnable.com/UUvAOjW8r6IwAAuN) (thanks @generalhenry).

So assume a user trying to create a post, already has been given a session id, that is sent with every request he makes by a cookie header. How can I access that cookie in the before hook (i.e. the `authorization` callback)?

The example can be started with `node app.js` and HTTP requests can be made using `curl`.

Comment: I made a runnable version http://runnable.com/UUvAOjW8r6IwAAuN

Comment: @generalhenry Thank you! So let's play with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that these guidelines are for authorization process. If you need to use sessionId you can access it either way: `req.sessionID`, `req.cookies["connect.sid"]`.

By checking requests this way you will be sure every users have valid session id.

```
app.use(flatiron.plugins.http, {
  before: [
    connect.favicon(),
    connect.cookieParser('catpsy speeds'),
    function(req, res) {
      if (req.originalUrl === undefined) {
        req.originalUrl = req.url;
      }
      res.emit('next');
    },
    connect.session({secret : 'secter'}),
    function(req, res) {
      console.log('Authenticating...');
      console.dir(req.session);
      //any other validation logic
      if (req.url !== '/login' && typeof req.session.user == 'undefined') {
        res.redirect('/login');
      } else {
        res.emit('next');
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Here is [project example](https://github.com/maiah/flatiron-auth/blob/master/app.js) using this approach.

Comment: Thank you for that example. It's very helpful. I'm not at work, so I can't try it immediately, but it looks promising, although it requires `connect` which I am not currently using. But I think I can factor out what it does. BTW, I improved indentation, so it's more readable and I don't think that `val === undefined` is good practise, so I changed it to `typeof val == 'undefined'`.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Check out best practices for jquery project at http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DJQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines%26redirect%3Dno point 4 and 5.

Comment: I still think that `typeof val == 'undefined'` is better, but ok.